# Unity determining ground via raycasting 2d

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Good evening!

I am trying to make a simple 2d platformer in unity without using rigidbodies, so I use raycast to determine where is the ground. I wrote this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class comtroller : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float velocity_y;
    private float velocity_x;

    private float speed_y = 1;
    private float speed_x = 10;

    private float localMinimum_y;



    //mask of the platform
    public LayerMask mask;

    void Update()
    {

        // raycast to sense platforms
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast((Vector2)transform.position , Vector2.down,Mathf.Infinity, mask);

        if (hit)
        {
            localMinimum_y = hit.point.y;
        }
        else
        {
            localMinimum_y = -10;
        }


        //determine whether the player can fall down
        // -0.6 is the distance between the player's transform.position and his legs
        if(transform.position.y -0.6f < localMinimum_y)
        {
            speed_y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            speed_y = 1;
        }


        //determine velocities

        velocity_y = speed_y * Physics2D.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity_x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed_x * Time.deltaTime;


        //movement
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(velocity_x, velocity_y));
    }




}
```

However, the player keeps stucking in the platform.
Can anyone help me where is the problem and how can I cure it?
Or if my idea is completely bad can you give any suggestion about how to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I recommend following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbWK8bCAU2w&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f0hqURlhyIoAabKPgRsqjz) tutorial if you want to go the non rigidbody way of making a 2d platformer game. It shows you how to manage raycast to make a character move on ground, slope, platforms and many other things. It's really ressourceful and will probably help you a lot.